Feature disappear when move off screen
I had a set my point feature to translate the point from its original position. The white points are its original position and the red points are the offset of the same features. However, the features disappear if the source of the feature are moved off screen. Is there a way to fix this?


You could actually move the points. If a feature isn't within the map window, it wont be displayed.

yes. but the red point features are geometry generator from the white point features. So if the source is off the screen, the point seen to not render.
